# Никак не могу вытянуть переменную

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Вот в чем проблема:
в console.log `msg` выводит, а вот когда доходит до редиректа то выдает is not defined. Наверное беда в зонах видимости переменных. Помогите...

Ниже код

```
success: function (msg) {
    $.fancybox('<div class="popup popup_sucsess"><p class="popup-title">Заявка принята!</p><p class="sucsess_text">Наш менеджер свяжется с вами в ближайшее время.<br/>Через <span class="size16">3</span> секунды Вы будете перенаправлены на страницу для оплаты.</p></div>',
                   {   'transitionIn': 'fade',
                       'transitionOut': 'fade',
                       'speedIn': 300,
                       'speedOut': 300,
                       'padding': 0,
                       'overlayColor': '#0080b0',
                       'overlayOpacity': 0.4,
                       'showNavArrows' : false
                   });
    setTimeout( 'document.location.replace(msg)', 3000 );
}
```

Comment: Переменная `msg` что содержит? Есть ли она?

Comment: да есть
содержыт адрес перенаправления на робокасу

Comment: в консоль выводит спокойно

Comment: Сделай `console.log(msg)` - посмотри, что будет в консоли.

Comment: делал выдает строку з url
все как и должно быть

Comment: url начинается с `http`?

Comment: Начинается с "https"

Вот console.log(msg)
https://auth.robokassa.ru/Merchant/Index.aspx?MrchLogin=SD_consult&OutSum=5.12&InvId=5&Desc=desc&SignatureValue=71d27b60d0f4f74543496f9337b37aa2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну да, функция же задаётся с помощью строки (зачем вообще так делать?), и информация о пространстве имён теряется. Надо задавать через функцию.

```
setTimeout(function(){document.location.replace(msg)}, 3000);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Просто ночь уже туплю. Сам с себя в шоке )